# PHP mail() vaildation

Tags: php

so i'm still relatively new to PHP and have been building a order form that can validate the fields before sending, as well as checking for spam.
From testing the below code works fine in returning errors and so on, but when I enter correct information I dont get any emails.
It was working fine before i added the Vaildation part to it but now im getting the problem above. Again i am still learning so any pointers would be nice, thanks

```
<?php
    function spamcheck($field) {
      $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
      if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return TRUE;
      } else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      ?>
```

Form

```
<?php } 
else 
{
    if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
        $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST["email"]);
        if ($mailcheck==FALSE) {
            echo "Invalid input";
            }
//field vailation
        else {
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $errors = array();
                if (!empty($_POST["fullname"])) {
                    $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
                    $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{2,20}/";
                    if (preg_match($pattern,$fullname)){ $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];}
                        else{ $errors[] = 'Your Name can only contain _, 1-9, A-Z or a-z 2-20 long.';}
                        } else {$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your First Name.';}

                if (!empty($_POST["contact"])) {
                    $contact = $_POST["contact"];
                    $pattern = "/^[0-9\_]{6,20}/";
                    if (preg_match($pattern,$contact)){ $contact = $_POST["contact"];}
                        else{ $errors[] = 'Your contact number can only be numbers, or is too short';}
                        } else {$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your contact number.';}
            }
//end vaildation
            else{
                $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
                $email = $_POST["email"];
                $address = $_POST["address"];
                $address2 = $_POST["address2"];
                $town = $_POST["town"];
                $postcode = $_POST["postcode"];
                $contact = $_POST["contact"];
                $shipping = $_POST["shipping"];
                $extra = $_POST["extra"];
                $extra = wordwrap($extra, 70);

                $message = '
                Full Name: ' . $fullname . '
                Delivery Address: ' . $address . '
                Delivery Address2: ' . $address2 . '
                Town/City: ' . $town . '
                Postal Code: ' . $postcode . '
                Contact: ' . $contact . '
                Email Address: ' . $email . '
                Special instructions: ' . $extra . '
                Shipping Method: ' . $shipping . '
                ';
                mail("myemail@myaddress.com","Order form",$message,"email: $email\n");
                echo 
                "<html>
                <body><br><br>
                Order successful, we will be in contact shortly<br>
                </body>
                </html>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($errors)) { 
        echo '<hr /><h3>The following occurred:</h3><ul>'; 
        foreach ($errors as $msg) { echo '<li>'. $msg . '</li>';}
        echo '</ul><h3>Your mail could not be sent due to input errors.</h3><hr />';}
        else{echo 
        "<html>
        <body><br><br>
        Order successful, we will be in contact shortly<br>
        </body>
        </html>";
    }
}
?>
```

After using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ive noticed that im getting an error `unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)` for the else at the top of the second block of code, so I tried moving code to :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
} 

else 
{
```

And left the form above this so that when the sumbit button is pressed the forms wont dissapear. Which is not giving me any errors but still not email once submitted

Comment: I recommend you to use an email library like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) to send emails because there are lots of different parameters that different servers may support or may not support. If you're getting an OK from `mail()` result, but you don't get the email, then there might be a problem with your mail header information.

Comment: Thanks, ill look into using that. As for this one, when i added the validation parts i didn't change any of the header info which is confusing me as to why im not getting an email

Comment: I can't really tell what's wrong. There might be a problem with your code or maybe a part of your message content that corrupts the mail. Try to set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before your code and see if there is any problem with the code.

Comment: Ive eddited it to reflect using that, but still no emails coming through sadly.

Comment: IMHO, [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) > PHPMailer